# 2016 WRX knocking sound - Codes

Tags: subaru, timing, cvt-transmission, wrx, rod

My 2016 had issues before this one which included - power loss. Loud idling when starting up. The power loss was an issue because sometimes turning right into traffic it would lose most all power I’d slam the gas to avoid causing an accident. Took it to 2 mechanics and the Subaru dealership. They couldn’t find out what was wrong. Fast forward to now, car started a really loud knocking sound coming from the engine area close to the left side near where the spark plugs area. Noise decreases a lot when car is warm but when I try to put gas or even move it’ll die off or stutter. So I haven’t moved it in almost a week. Throwing codes p0011 p0014 p000a p000b p0012 which all have to do somewhat related with the time belt. It’s extremely frustrating because I have no warranty or extended so it’ll all be out of pocket. Cars loaned so I still have to pay and I’m afraid it could be a rod which would be a whole engine swap so thousands of dollars which I don’t have.
Anyone out there with some knowledge on this subject? If it’s the timing belt tensioner I wouldn’t mind towing it to a repair shop and paying 300-500 to get it fixed but if it’s a rod I wouldn’t want to waste money on towing or diagnostics.

2016 wrx CVT 61,000miles.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  It sounds to me like the VVT actuator or solenoid has gone bad. P0011 and P0014 both point to this. This "might" happen if you are using the wrong weight oil as required by the manufacturer, or if either one of those parts are bad.

Comment: I did not go to a specific page I just posted on MVM and repair. I’ve done a lot of research and it combined with the codes and the sound of it. I’m between the belt tensioner or a rod. No idea